# have done(experience) / did(specific time)

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

Could you tell me if I am wrong:

I can say "The maximum I have done is 20km" because it's experience.
And I should say "The maximum I did was 20km but because the ground was flat" because I talk about one specific time.

Comment: Sounds about correct, but could you add some context to it? What are you referring to when you say you've 'done' something?

Comment: In the situation: I injured my leg not long time ago, and a friend of mine ask me "Could you walk" and I reply "The maximum I did was 20km but because the ground was flat", is it correct?

Comment: Yes, for the specific case mentioned, it's correct